# How can I generate an ID that will reset every year?

Tags: vb.net

I need help in VB.net I'm a newbie in programming.

I have a problem in generating an ID with the format

```
`yyyy` = now.year
`mm` = now.month
`0000` = auto number
```

I want to increment the auto number everytime I add records
so it goes like this

```
2014090001
```

and also it will reset back to `0000` when year changes.

Comment: You should keep track of the last ID inserted. Not an easy task if your app is used concurrently by more than one user. More information is needed. What database are you using? Could you show how do you store this id?

Comment: Encoding multiple data items in a single field is never not a mistake.  Add separate fields for year and month, generating the ID should be a separate task best taken care of by the data storage provider.

Comment: Why not just add a timestamp or DateCreated column?  it doesnt have  to be part of the ID field especially if you are already using an autonumber.

Comment: I generally use a "KeyManager" to keep track of the last id. You have to request a new ID for each record you want to add. The "KeyManager" wil manage the whole looping for you. If I am not mistaken, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 has something like that nowadays built-in.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for all your replies, I took all your advice and I got a solution CONSIDER THIS THREAD AS CLOSE!!

my final solution is creating another table in database with the fields ID, counter, and YEAR
I created a condition that will test the current year, so if the year = now.year the counter will just increment by 1 and if year <> to now.year then the counter will back to 0. it will add up another records  in that table so the use of ID is to delete the previous records.